# ACF - if field has value within Field Group conditional statement

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a field group(product specs) with bunch of sub fields. I want to put the subfields all within a container. Id like a field group if statement, there is none to be found: in docs, on the ACF site and here. Making me think am going about it wrong. I can live with an empty table however it feels so wrong.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php

if(get_field_group('field_group_name'))
{
    echo '<table>';
    if(get_field('field_name'))
    {
        echo '<td>' . get_field('field_name') . '</td>';
    }


    if(get_field('field_name'))
    {
        echo '<td>' . get_field('field_name') . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}


?>
```

Comment: your `if statement` is wrong

Comment: @ma_dev_15 brilliant!

Comment: I don't believe get_field_group() is a real function. Could you try and explain a bit more exactly what you are trying to do. Are you sure 'field group' is that right term?

Comment: Get field group is not a real function. Its an example of what I would like to do. But there is no documentation. A Field group is were you can place a set of custom fields within the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted on ACF site, they were very helpful in finding the solution.

```
if( get_field('field_name') && get_field('field_name')) {
}
```

Was that solution I was looking for. I knew it was never asked because it was simple logic :/ Slowly learning as I go. Hope this helps someone.